# Unrecognised symbols in GNU APL

Tags: primitive, apl, gnu-apl

I am playing around with GNU APL, but my experiments quickly reached an impasse.
This is what happened:

```
x←1 2 3 4 5
⍝ build the matrix u where u_{ij} = x_i + x_j,
⍝ then filter the entries equal to 6
u←6=x∘.+x
```

So far so good, `u` is a flipped identity matrix, as expected.

Now, I would like to get the indices of the nonzero entries, so I try

```
⍸u
```

but here I get a `SYNTAX ERROR++` warning.
The same error appears when entering any of the following commands:

```
{⍸6=⍵∘.+⍵}x
{⍸6=⍵∘.+⍵} 1 2 3 4 5
{⍸6=⍵∘.+⍵} ⍳5
app←{⍸6=⍵∘.+⍵}
```

I suspect this is somehow a problem on my local installation, as I cannot reproduce the errors on the [online interpreter](http://juergen-sauermann.de/try-GNU-APL).

Did somebody see this problem before?
I compiled APL from source (ubuntu, GCC), the error appears in both versions 1.7 and 1.8.
I could reproduce the error with the precompiled binary available from GNU's mirror.
I wonder if I made a mistake in compiling and installing GNU APL, but the only non-standard thing I did was to unset the flag WERROR from the Makefile in the src folder, otherwise it would not compile due to an unchecked return value in the source.

Comment: Not a solution, but you can implement `⍸` as `{(,⍵)/,⍳⍴⍵}`

Comment: Please note the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed bug-apl@gnu.org to get someone to have a look. This is the response I got:

> no idea. I am getting this:
>
> ```
>       ⍝ build the matrix u where u_{ij} = x_i + x_j,
>       ⍝ then filter the entries equal to 6
>       u←6=x∘.+x
>  
>       ⍸u  1 5  2 4  3 3  4 2  5 1
> ```
>
> SVN is 18005 aka. 1474 and the related code has not changed für years.
>
> Regarding:
>
> "otherwise it would not compile due to an unchecked return value in
> the source."
>
> please report this kind of problems to bug-apl@gnu.org with a printout
> of the compiler's error message. Compilers are becoming increasingly
> picky about various this which causes code to happily compile for a
> decade an then out of a sudden raise a warning with a new compiler
> code.
>
> I have the ambition that GNU APL compiles on almost all platforms and
> compilers and since I cannot test all platforms on my own it is
> important that users like you with a different platform inform me
> about problems.
>
> Best Regards,
> [Dr.] Jürgen [Sauermann, the main developer of GNU APL]

---

## Edit per the [GNU APL mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-apl/2021-06/msg00035.html):

Support for `⍸` was added in December 2020 (r1368). Released tarballs don't have it; you will have to compile the development version from the repository to get it.

Note that tarballs are not the preferred way of installing GNU APL.

Comment: It seems that the source downloads from FTP (i.e. the `apl-1.8-0.src.rpm`) doesn't have the impl of `⍸`, but the git repository does. Maybe that's the issue here?

Comment: I had no hope of receiving an answer so quickly! Thank you very much!

Comment: As for the compiler warnings, a couple that I found are these:
`APmain.cc:137:1: warning: 'noreturn' function does return
 }
 ^`  and `Shape.hh: In member function ‘Shape Shape::insert_axis(Axis, ShapeItem) const’:
Shape.hh:68:46: error: ‘*(const ShapeItem*)((char*)& ret + <unknown> *8 +8)’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
   68 |      loop(r, MAX_RANK)   rho[r] = other.rho[r];` there are others but I can't fit them all here. The compiler is g++ 10.3.0.

Comment: @J.D. Will you forward that to the mailing list?

Comment: Hi @Adám no need to worry about that: I re-installed GNU APL from the repository (same compiler, -Werror enabled), and all the warnings disappeared. I would recommend the team to update the tarballs to a more recent version, or alternatively to remove the -Werror flag, though. My problem with `⍸` is completely solved now!